# PHP "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" on shared server

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm working with PHP 5 here. I have the following code:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
foreach ($data as $obj) {
......

}
```

I get the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" on the line with the foreach function. This only happens on my shared server account. On my local webserver everything works fine. $_POST['data'] contains valid JSON string. print_r($data); shows nothing...What the hell is wrong here ?

**EDIT:** It really blows my mind but the $_POST['data'] string is being sent with AJAX and I catch the string with FireBug and copied into a JSON test file like this:

```
$data = json_decode('[{"id":3,"name":"John","surname":"Smith","number":6633,"city":"The city","area":"West","street":"West","numar":"15","other":"none"},{"id":3,"name":"John","surname":"Smith","number":6633,"city":"The city","area":"West","street":"West","numar":"15","other":"none"},{"id":3,"name":"John","surname":"Smith","number":6633,"city":"The city","area":"West","street":"West","numar":"15","other":"none"}]');
print_r($data);
```

And it comes out as it should, properly. So I'm gonna paste more code from the function that troubles:

```
function saveData($table)
{
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);    

    $db = new MySQL(true);
    $db->TransactionBegin();

    foreach ($data as $obj) {
  $id = $obj->id;
  $name = $obj->name;
}
}
```

Check this out: If I do this:

```
$data = json_decode('[{"id":3,"name":"John","surname":"Smith","number":6633,"city":"The city","area":"West","street":"West","numar":"15","other":"none"},{"id":3,"name":"John","surname":"Smith","number":6633,"city":"The city","area":"West","street":"West","numar":"15","other":"none"},{"id":3,"name":"John","surname":"Smith","number":6633,"city":"The city","area":"West","street":"West","numar":"15","other":"none"}]');
foreach ($data as $obj) {
......

}
```

Works perfect! So there seems to be e problem when I do:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

But $_POST['data'] outputs a perfect JSON string. It's driving me crazy.

Any ideas ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

magic_quotes_gpc... Quote from php.net:

> When on, all ' (single-quote), "
>   (double quote), \ (backslash) and NULL
>   characters are escaped with a
>   backslash automatically.

As it turns out magic quotes is enabled on the shared server. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump($data)` will presumably show that `$data` is `null`.  From [the docs](http://www.php.net/json_decode):

> NULL is returned if the json  cannot
>   be decoded or if the encoded data is
>   deeper than the recursion limit.

If the behavior is special to your shared server, perhaps it has a lower recursion limit than your local server.

Comment: Okay.  Not seeing anything about your edit that affects my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` is only present on `PHP 5 >= 5.2.0` with `PECL json >= 1.2.0`, so my guess is that your hosting is using a lower version.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause an error (indeed a fatal error) for calling an undefined function before even reaching foreach?

Comment: That would throw a fatal error on `json_decode()` not existing.

Comment: I had this situation before, and the PHP (on a shared hosting too) had the json_encode function, but not the PECL and didn't gave an error. I didn't had access to the logs, so I got no certainty of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`$data` is invalid JSON? (Either malformed or empty)